# Summing over n adjacent columns

Tags: javascript, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a short function which will sum n adjacent columns to the right of a start cell. This is what I've got so far:

```
function CalculateSum(X,n) {
 var sum=0;
 for (var i=1; i<n; i+=1) {
 sum=sum+values[i][0];
 }
 return sum;
}
```

I need to somehow set cell X as the start point of the sum, but just can't work out how to do this!

Comment: This is with Google spreadsheets? Is this a custom function to put in a cell or something to call via appscript? For a cell function, you may want to check out [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en). Use `INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW( ) ; COLUMN( ) )` as the `cell_reference` if you don't want to use the direct cell (e.g. A1). In Appscript, you can use [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)), n being the number of columns.